# Level 3 <nav> not hiding when it should

Tags: html, css

I'm turning a 2 level `<nav>` into a 3 level and running into a few difficulties.

The 3rd level displays where and as predicted but when the 'grandparent' is hovered over, not the parent of the items I want displayed.

I've been fooling around with the CSS for a while and I cannot get it to respond how I'd like.

Any help is appreciated.

There is a fiddle as my explanation might be somewhat lacking.

http://jsfiddle.net/6TGaf/

Code from fiddle:

```
    #nav{
    background: #bada55;
    width: 99%;
    margin-top:-5px;
}

#nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 40px;
}

#nav ul li{
    /*child elements positioned absolutley will be relative to this*/
    position: relative;
    border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    float: left;

}

#nav a{
    color: ghostwhite;
    padding: 12px 0px;
    /*fill hori space*/
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
/*apply transition to background property, taking 1s to change it
*/
    transition:padding 1s, background 1s;
    -moz-transition:padding 1s, background 1s;
    -webkit-transition:padding 1s, background 1s;
    -o-transition:padding 1s, background 1s;

    font-family:tahoma;

    font-size:13px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding-left:20px;
}

/*hover pseduo class*/
#nav a:hover{
    /*
    RGBA background for transparancy:
    last number(0.05) is the transparency
    */
    padding-left:35px;
    background: RGBA(255,255,255,0.05);
    color:#fff;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul{
    /*diplay when hovered*/
    display: block;
}

#nav ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 40px;
    border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    display: none;
    /*width: 304px;*/
    z-index: 1;
}

#nav ul ul li{
    width: 150px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    border-top: 0;
    /*float:left;*/

}

#nav ul ul li a{
    color:#000000;
    font-size:12px;
    text-transform:none;
}

#nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color:#929292;
}

/*3rd level...*/
#nav ul ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    display: none;
    /*width: 304px;*/
    z-index: 1;
}

#nav ul ul ul li{
    width: 150px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    border-top: 0;
}

#nav ul ul ul li a{
    color:#000000;
    font-size:12px;
    text-transform:none;
}

#nav ul ul ul li a:hover {
color:#929292;
}

#nav ul ul li:hover ul{
/*diplay when hovered*/
display: block;
}

<nav id = "nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">1.1</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">1.1.1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">1.1.1.a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">1.1.1.b</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="#">1.1.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1.1.3</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
#nav ul li:hover ul {
    /*diplay when hovered*/
    display: block;
}
```

to

```
#nav ul li:hover>ul {
    /*diplay when hovered*/
    display: block;
}
```

Note the extra ">"

Edit: 
Added [jsFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/validide/6TGaf/11/)

Comment: Brilliant thanks!  Does that force it to only display as a block when it's a child of that parent?

Comment: Yes, it forces the "ul" element to be a direct child of the "li" element

Comment: Thanks again, it's a real elegant solution. I hadn't even considered it :(

Answer (score 1):

just add this piece of code it will work for you

```
#nav ul li:hover ul ul{
    /*diplay when hovered*/
    display: none;
}
```